# RaspberryPiへ外部からアクセスしたい

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, http

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+を使用しています。
raspberry piでサーバーを立てて外部からhttp接続がしたいのですが、外部からのアクセスが成功しません。
ローカルの別のPCからのアクセスは成功しました。

apacheのインストール、IPアドレスの固定、ポートフォワーディングの設定は行いました。

apacheのインストールは[ここ](https://qiita.com/KAKY/items/55e6c54fa2073cdc0bbe#apache-php%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)の通りに行いました。
ポートフォワーディングは、外部からの80番ポートへのアクセスを固定したIPアドレスの80番ポートへ転送するように設定しました。

この状態で、raspberryで`curl ifconfig.io`で表示されたグローバルIPを、スマホのブラウザのURL欄に入力しましたが成功しませんでした。
net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTEDと表示されます。

失敗する原因はどこなのでしょうか。

Comment: ポートフォワーディングを設定しているのはルータでしょうか？ルータのログに何か手がかりが残っているかもしれません。

Comment: ルータのWan側は固定IPを持っているのですか？　インターネット(Wan側）から、raspberryまでのネットワーク構成を示してください。　また、スマホでルータのWan側固定IPの80番ポートにアクセスしてみてください。何が起こりますか？